# How to add input cells to a transposed table using CSS, HTML, JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am dynamically adding to a transposed table. Adding the headers works; however when I add the table details (td) they appear under the table instead of to the right.

CSS to transpose table:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr, tbody { display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
```

Table HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr id="tableHeaders">
        <!-- Place for exercise headers -->
    </tr>
                                
    <tbody id="tableBody">
        <tr>
            <td>20/04/2021</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>27/04/2021</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
                                    
        <!-- Place for exercise details -->
    </tbody>
                                    
</table>
```

js to populate table:

```
//Populate the variable number of headers and keep count.
var numHeaders = 1;
$("<th>Date</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeaders"));
$.each(responseJson1a, function() {
    $("<th>"+ this.edeType + " - " + this.edeUnit + "</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeaders"));
        
    numHeaders++;
});

//Create an input detail cell for each header 
$("<tr>").appendTo($("#tableBody"));
            
for(let i = 0; i < numHeaders; i++) {
    $("<td><input></td>").appendTo($("#tableBody"));
}
            
$("</tr>").appendTo($("#tableBody"));
```

This is the result:

[image]

The table should look like:

[image]

This is what the table would look like when not transposed:

[image]

Comment: A few points of clarification: 1) What's a "transposed table"? I'm unfamiliar with this term 2) You have shown how it is currently displaying, but I am not clear on how it is _supposed_ to be displaying; can you please explain this?

Comment: @AlexanderNied A transposed table has the headings on the left instead of along the top. The three input boxes should in-line with the headings on the left (Date, Speed - km/h and Incline - Deg.). I will create a mock up to show this and update the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding inputs inside `tbody` not inside any tr tag . So , you can just use `:last` this will refer tr tag which is added last and then inside this tr you can add your inputs .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//just for demo..
var responseJson1a = [{
  "edeType": "Speed",
  "edeUnit": "km/h"
}, {
  "edeType": "Speed",
  "edeUnit": "km/h"
}]
var numHeaders = 1;
$("<th>Date</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeaders"));
$.each(responseJson1a, function() {
  $("<th>" + this.edeType + " - " + this.edeUnit + "</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeaders"));
  numHeaders++;
});
$("<tr></tr>").appendTo($("#tableBody"));//new tr..
for (let i = 0; i < numHeaders; i++) {
  $("<td><input></td>").appendTo($("#tableBody tr:last")); //append to last tr which is added
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr,
tbody {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

th,
td {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
    <!--move it inside-->
    <tr id="tableHeaders">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20/04/2021</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>27/04/2021</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Place for exercise details -->
  </tbody>

</table>
```